# Yii2: How can I pass an array to RESTful Web Services

Tags: api, yii2

How can I pass an array from frontend to my `API`? I tried to pass it via body param

`Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam("arrayParam")`

But am not able to get that array it returns a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handling API for easy way - none optimal solution- by adding

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
```

to your action, then you can return any array you want....

but if you have folder like fronted, back-end and API, you need to work or process data in API controller, and do not pass data between these ends by array or session...

Example:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $user = \app\models\User::find($id);
    return $user;
}
```

useful link:

- [Create Api End](http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/)